# Bootstrap Card components not rendering in React

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, meteor

I'm using bootstrap for styling my react app. This is working great most of the time. However for some reason I can't render Card components correctly. Other bootstrap components like Navbar and forms work great - it's just the card components that are mis-behaving.

Other than renaming class to className, is anything else necessary for rendering cards? Complete code below. Any insight greatly appreciated!

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
export default class CardCollectionWrapper extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {


    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
    }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
    }

    loadMore() {
    }

    sortBy(){
    }

    render() {
    return(
      <div className="card-deck-wrapper">
      <div className ="container">
        <div className="card-deck">
          <div className="card">
            <img className="card-img-top" src="/images/wire240.jpeg" alt="Card image cap"/>
            <div className="card-block">
              <h4 className="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <p className="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <p className="card-text"><small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="card">
            <img className="card-img-top" src="/images/wireframe.png" alt="Card image cap"/>
            <div className="card-block">
              <h4 className="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <p className="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <p className="card-text"><small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="card">
            <img className="card-img-top" src="/images/wireframe.png" alt="Card image cap"/>
            <div className="card-block">
              <h4 className="card-title">Card title</h4>
              <p className="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
              <p className="card-text"><small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )}}
```

Comment: Did you load Bootstrap 3 or 4? Cards are only available in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Nailed it! I'm using the atmosphere twbs package -which appears to be bootstrap 3. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bootstrap version 3 `meteor add twbs:bootstrap`, which does not contain the Card Component. Thanks Yang Shun